# How to use Dropzone with laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, dropzone.js

i want to incorporate 'Dropzone' to my website with Laravel 4.2 , I found an example in their official website [here](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) .

But when I add it to my form, the form changes behavior and I can't processed the image in the controller. could you give me an basic example of dropzone with Laravel 4.2?

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
                        var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzone", {
                            url: "{{URL::route('compose-attachment')}}",
                            //clickable: "#yourSubmitButton",
                            paramName: "file",
                            addRemoveLinks: true,
                            init: function() {

                                        });
                                    });
                            }
                        });
                    </script>
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/compose-attachment', array( 'as' => 'postMsgAttachment','uses' => 'UserController@getPostAttachment'));
```

Controller:

```
public function getPostAttachment(){


 $file = Input::file('file');
 $destinationPath =  public_path().'/uploads';
 $time = time();

 $filename = $time."-".$file->getClientOriginalName(); 
 $upload_success = Input::file('file')->move($destinationPath, $filename);
 }
```

Comment: I got this error (Route [/compose-attachment] not defined.)

Comment: Is your controller also named UserController?

Comment: ArticleController , But i renamed route to : Route::post('/compose-attachment', array( 'as' => 'postMsgAttachment','uses' => 'ArticleController@getPostAttachment'));

Comment: You should have two Routes: Route::post('/compose-attachment', array( 'as' => 'postMsgAttachment','uses' => 'ArticleController@getPostAttachment')); To post dropzone files. and a get Route to render your view. Same goes for Controller. In your Controller you should have two functions, one two render the view that is your "get" Route and the second function for the "post" Route

Comment: Yes i have two routes , Can you please give me also form code (Form that contain drapzone div)

Comment: I am not using dropzone in a form. I only have <di id="dropzone"></div> That was why I commented out this line: //clickable: "#yourSubmitButton" So if u are using it in a form you uncomment that line to send file after submit button.

Comment: The same error (Route [compose-attachment] not defined.) :\

Comment: Can you put your full code here. Route, Controller and dropzone initialization

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79559/discussion-between-aid-and-michel).

Answer (score 0):

This is my View code :

```
{{ Form::open(array('files'=> true  , 'method' => 'post' ,'route' => array('article.create', Route::current()->getParameter('lang')))) }}

                  <div class="fallback" id = "dropzone" >
                    <input name="file" type="file" multiple />
                  </div>

        {{ Form::submit(Lang::get('messages.create') , array('class' => 'btn btn-default custom-submit')) }}

    {{ Form::close() }}
<script>
var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#dropzone", {
    url: "{{URL::route('compose-attachment')}}",
    //clickable: "#yourSubmitButton",
    paramName: "file",
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    init: function() {

                });
            });
    }
});
</script>
```

Routes :

```
Route::post('/compose-attachment', array( 'as' => 'postMsgAttachment','uses' => 'ArticleController@getPostAttachment'));
```

Controller :

```
public function getPostAttachment(){
        $file = Input::file('file');
        return var_dump($file);
    }
```